# PowerEdge 2850 boot issue due to lost raid config

Tags: raid, boot, dell-poweredge, data-recovery

I have an older dell PowerEdge 2850 that has a boot issue when the server boots it comes up with the error pxe- e53 no boot filename received.

I believe the raid card and memory where pulled and as such the raid config and boot setup is missing and this is the reason for the above error

The server has 6 ULTRA-320 SCSI drives in it (FC272). I don't want to loose the data on the drives so want to make sure that when I re-setup the raid it does not wipe the drives. but my issue is i don't know what the original raid setup was so not sure how I should attempt to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

A Dell PERC will be able to import the configuration from the disks as "Foreign Configuration". You should be able to access the controller's management interface and import the foreign configuration.